# Referencing a dynamic associative array position

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm requesting data from an online source which I then decode into json StdClass objects (using php). Once I've done this I have the following (see below). I'm trying to extract the elements in 'otherstuff' by doing `echo $response->stuff->WHAT GOES HERE?->otherstuff`

However I cant hard code the [2010-12] because its a date, is there any way I can call e.g. `$response->stuff->nextsibling->stuff`

I hope this makes sense to someone :D Currently i'm bastardising this with a `$key => $value` for loop and extracting the key value and using it in my `$response->stuff->$key->stuff` call.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [commentary] => 
    [stuff] => stdClass Object
        (
            **[2010-12]** => stdClass Object
                (
                    [otherstuff] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [otherstuffrate] => 1
                            [otherstufflevel] => 1
                            [otherstufftotal] => 1
                        )    
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StdClass instances can be used with some [Array Functions](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php), among them

- [`current` — Return the current element in an array](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) and
- [`key` — Fetch a key from an array](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php)

So you can do ([codepad](http://codepad.org/6ZzFp8lY))

```
$obj = new StdClass;
$obj->{"2012-10"} = 'foo';
echo current($obj); // foo
echo key($obj); // 2012-10
```

On a sidenote, object properties should not start with a number and they may not contain dashes, so instead of working with StdClass objects, pass in `TRUE` as the second argument to `json_decode`. Returned objects will be converted into associative arrays then.

Comment: I wasn't too sure how to implement your method. However I've managed to get what I needed using this; $foo = current($response->stuff), this then gives me the object which has 'otherstuff'. It doesn't seem like it should have worked but it does :D

Comment: @Garbit this is correct usage. `current($response->stuff)` will give you the object stored in the date property. While `key($response->stuff)` will give you the name of the date property. There is no reason to use `array_key` as shown elsewhere. `Current` and `Key` will work with an array *or* the StdClass object.

Answer (score 0):

The date key must be a string, otherwise PHP breaks ;).

```
echo $response->stuff['2010-12']->otherstuff
```

Retrieve it using a string.

Comment: You might want to reread the question. What happens when you try to access an object not implementing ArrayAccess with array notation? "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array".

Comment: The 2010-12 part is dynamic therefore I cant use this method

Answer (score 0):

Edited again: added object code also

json decode it as associative array, and use key fetched through `array_keys` . See it work here : http://codepad.org/X8HCubIO

```
    <?php

$str = '{
       "commentary" : null,
        "stuff" : {
            "ANYDATE" : {
                "otherstuff": {
                    "otherstuffrate" : 1,
                    "otherstufflevel" : 1,
                    "otherstufftotal" : 1
                }
            }
        }
      }';

$obj = json_decode($str,true);
$reqKey = array_keys($obj["stuff"]);
$req = $obj["stuff"][$reqKey[0]]["otherstuff"];
print_r($req);
print "====================as object ============\n";
$obj = json_decode($str);
$req = current($obj->stuff)->otherstuff; 
print_r($req);
?>
```

Comment: Undefined offset: 0 -> unfortunately this doesn't work it would seem :(

Comment: @garbit, you are welcome,i added code to decode it  as object also.

Comment: using `array_keys` is superfluous. The code to access the object works for the array (except you cannot chain it) as well because `current` is an array function in the first place.