# how to get array key dynamically for checking the condition in php?

Tags: php, arrays, static, key

I have one array, for example

```
$test_input= array(
  0=> array(
    "task" => 'ColumnTree Example',
    "duration" => '3 hours',
    "user"=> '',
    "uiProvider" => 'col',
    "cls" => 'master-task',
    "iconCls" => 'task-folder',
    'children'=> array(
      0 => array(
        "task" => 'Abstract rendering in TreeNodeUI',
        "duration" => '15 min',
        "user" => 'Jack Slocum',
        "uiProvider" => 'col',
        "leaf" => true,
        "iconCls" => 'task'
      ),
      array(
        "task" => 'Test and make sure it works',
        "duration" => '1 hour',
        "user" => 'Jack Slocum',
        "uiProvider" => 'col',
        "leaf" =>true,
        "iconCls" =>'task'
      )
    )
  ),
  array(
    "task" => 'Custom Field Example',
    "duration" => '2 1/2 hours',
    "user" => '',
    "uiProvider" => 'col',
    "cls" => 'master-task',
    "iconCls" => 'task-folder',
    'children'=>array(
      0 => array(
        "task" =>'Implement "Live Search" on extjs.com from Alex',
        "duration" =>'1 hour',
        "user" =>'Jack Slocum',
        "uiProvider" =>'col',
        "leaf" =>true,
        "iconCls"=> 'task'
      ),
      array(
        "task"=>'Extend TwinTrigger',
        "duration"=>'30 min',
        "user"=>'Jack Slocum',
        "uiProvider"=>'col',
        "leaf"=>true,
        "iconCls"=>'task'
      )
    )
  ),
  array(
    "task"=>'Foo Bar Item',
    "duration"=>'3 hours',
    "user"=>'',
    "uiProvider"=>'col',
    "cls"=>'master-task',
    "iconCls"=>'task-folder',
    'children'=>array(
      0 => array(
        "task"=>'Abstract rendering in TreeNodeUI',
        "duration"=>'15 min',
        "user"=>'Jack Slocum',
        "uiProvider"=>'col',
        "leaf"=>true,
        "iconCls"=>'task'
      ),
      array( 
        "task"=>'Create TreeNodeUI with column knowledge',
        "duration"=>'45 min',
        "user"=>'Jack Slocum',
        "uiProvider"=>'col',
        "leaf"=>true,
        "iconCls"=>'task'
      )
    )
  )
);
```

I want to do some stuff. By checking condition

```
if($key=="task")
 {
   something/.........
 }
```

So here instead of statically giving key value as 'task'. I need that should come dynamically.
I am using `array_map` for mapping my function and my array. Please give me some examples on how to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152694/php-referencing-a-dynamic-associative-array-position/5152747#5152747

Comment: Please give us an example of how you use it.

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? It is probably easier to use `foreach`.

Comment: Formatting this array almost made me sober.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a foreach statement? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use foreach for this. Whether you use foreach for this task but you have to check this as you are doing.

Because by using foreach you can get key and value pair but to check something you have to put condition.

Answer (score 0):

From your data structure, it looks like, you need to do [recursion](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29). Try this code:

```
function walk_array($array, &$returnData, $depth = 0)
{
    $depth++;
    foreach( $array as $key=>$value)
    {
        $returnData[] = $value['task'];

        if( isset( $value['children'] ) && is_array( $value['children'] ) )
        {
            walk_array($value['children'], &$returnData, $depth);
        }
    }
}
```

Test it like this:

```
$returnData = array();
walk_array($test_input, &$returnData);
echo implode("<br />", $returnData);
```

One thing to note regarding recursion
is, be careful when designing the
code. One tiny mistake could end up
looping infinitely.